# How to get the name of the signer from a signed file

Tags: c#, powershell, cryptography, digital-signature

I am trying to get the name of the signers from a signed files using PowerShell.

The signer of FlashUtil_ActiveX.exe (in Windows 10) is “Microsoft Windows Third Party Application Component”:
[image]
*Checked with Right Click on the file*

[image]
*Checked with Sigcheck.exe*

When I tried it with powershell it shows me different names:
[image]

Any of the names (the “Subject” and the “Issuer”) are not “Microsoft Windows Third Party Application Component”.

I also tried with `Get-AppLockerFileInformation` with no success:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to use the `Get-PfxCertificate` command.
Now I can see the name of the signer appeared in the "Signature list".

This is how it looks using the command:
[image]

And this is an example for file (igfxSDK.exe) with number of signatures:
[image]

Comment: Cool. Thanks for reporting back and +1. You may be able to indicate this as the answer by now (~ 48 hours).